# How to comment each change in files so they will be visible for git but hidden in actual files

Tags: git, phpstorm, atlassian-sourcetree

When I develop a feature I usually need to change non-related files: utils, helpers. But not only those. There are cases when event some repository is not related to the feature but it just contains additional code to allow developing of the main feature.

Initially I just skipped this problem. But now I understand that it is difficult to understand why I changed some files if they are not related to the feature I committed. I need something like usual comments in files but they should be visible just for git: when I browse commit message/history I want to see why I did a specific change. I can not comment each change. The biggest problem is that my change could be not just adding code lines but removing. Nobody need to see comments for the absent lines.

My first idea is to commit changes with comments in files and then do another commit to remove comments. By it is like a workaround. I work in PhpStorm. And I always see git history there. I want to open a file from commit and see why I did some change. I would be very useful for me. Very useful. For me it give the same profit as I have from commit message.

I do not see other solutions. Maybe someone else had such problem.

I also assume that other git GUI programs could have such a feature.

Answer (score 2):

Just a list of ideas to try.

1. Use github or bitbucket's comments. They are quite nice. The downside is that they are stored in own format of the server and not accessible locally.
2. Use notes; run `git notes add <commit>`, then you have an editor where you can insert (partial) diffs and comment them. They are stored in git's database, and would be relatively convenient to use if you can afford command-line. But popular tools are quite behind in their support.
3. Commit changes to your helper files separately. That way, you have a dedicated place to comment them. But then you will have to not squash your pull-request merges, so that the history is preserved, or make separated PRs.
4. Consider re-organizing your helpers and make the ones you have to touch internal to your implementations. Indeed, if they have problem specific functionality it is dangerous to have them detached, somebody can start using them to unrelated purpose. So that the changes will look very much less detached.
5. Do *not* remove comments in the file. If some operations are not obvious from the function name maybe it is ok to have the  reasoning behind them commented.

Comment: Note (heh) that you can add notes for anything Git records, including blobs and trees.  To add a note to specific content you just committed, `git notes add :that/file.txt` (note the leading colon).

Comment: Did not know about git notes. Regarding the point #4, not sure you understood me. Helper is still helper. I just add methods to it when I needed. That's all. They are still universal. For example, I have `ProductsCollection` - initially it just extends doctrine's collection. But it grows as I need new functionality.

Comment: @jthill I'm afraid they would be even harder to discover then.

Answer (score 1):

Well, why not using the git commit message for that?

You can add several lines to a commit message by putting many `-m` parameters:

```
git commit -m "My commit message (headline)" -m "Second line" -m "third line..."
```

Or if you don't want to write this way, you can setup the editor and when you run `git commit`, it will open your editor to write your long commit message, so there you can explain everything you need, why you changed the files and so on.

To setup the editor, just run:

```
git config core.editor vim
```

PS: I recommend looking how people write commit messages in great repositories, like the linux one (https://github.com/torvalds/linux). Look how descriptive are the messages there and be inspired :)

Comment: It is a good idea. But few weaknesses. When file change is visible in commit message, I need to search that file manually. Another side, I may want to see changes in a specific file with my comments (like in PhpStorm "show file history"). But your suggestion is still worthy.